# GNOME BUILDER как установить C# Linux

Tags: c#, linux, install, gnome, builder

Как установить в редактор кода GNOME BUILDER поддержку языка программирования С#?[image: Невозможно выбрать язык С#.] Dotnet у меня установлен. Linux Fedora 36.

Comment: вообще есть команда dotnet new https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new